# Calling controller function from directive does not update view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am creating an application where an Ajax request fetches a list of packages from server and displays them.
After that I have created a directive called "packageDetails" which is applied to an individual package.

The directive has to do 2 things:

1- Fetch the details from server via an AJAX request when element is clicked

2- Pick up some HTML from elsewhere in the page and insert it just next to the package that was clicked.

My problem: On clicking a package AJAX request is getting the details from server and DOM is being manipulated. I can also see that the scope variable `$scope.packageDetails` gets updated in controller. But the changes do not reflect in view. **However, if i click once more on a package, the view gets updated this time.**

What I have tried so far:

Used scope.$apply in both directive and controller. This seemed to be the most common issue for other developers but did not fix my issue.

Tried using ng-click in element but no luck.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tMrJB2mBUdv26WdCg7Xv?p=preview)**

Here is the code:

Controller

```
/*
an array that creates the rows and columns
$scope.packageList = [];
*/
$scope.getPackageDetails = function (packageId) {
    console.log('get details for ' + packageId);
    ajaxService.getPackageDetails(packageId).then(function (data) {
        if (parseInt(data.ResponseStatus, 10) === 0) {
            $scope.packageDetails = data.Packages;
            // i have tried $scope.$apply() here; doesn't work
        }
    });
```

View

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="columnPackages in packageList">
    <div class="col-md-3 onePackage" ng-repeat="package in columnPackages" package-details package-id="{{package.Id}}" click="getPackageDetails"  has-response="response" >
        <figure>
            <a class="package_view">
                <strong>{{package.Name}}</strong>
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive

```
epApp.directive('packageDetails', function () {
    return {
        scope:
        {
            hasResponse: '=hasResponse',
            click: '=click'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {            
            if (scope.$parent.$last) {
                $(elem).parent('div.row').find('div.onePackage').on('click', function () {
                    /* some dom manipulation */
                    var packages_content = jQuery('.packages_widget_append').html();
                    jQuery(this).closest(".row").after(packages_content);

                    /* called parent controller function to get the details*/
                    console.log('clicked ' + parseFloat(attrs.packageId));
                    scope.click(parseFloat(attrs.packageId));
                    // i have tried $scope.$apply() here as well; doesn't work

                });
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get an error when you call $apply?  And have you tried using $timeout (with no delay) instead?

Comment: If I call $apply in directive, then no error but if I call it from controller just after response is received, I get an error `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
z/<@http://localhost/EPV2/js/vendor/angular.min.js:6:450`.

Comment: As c0bra mentioned, try wrapping it around $timeout with no delay. That won't give you digest in progress error.

Comment: @AbhishekJain tried timeout without delay as well. Still not working.

Comment: Can you create a plunker for this?

Comment: Here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/tMrJB2mBUdv26WdCg7Xv?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

1.: Did you forget put argument for your function? :-)

```
click="getPackageDetails(package.Id)"
```

instead of

```
click="getPackageDetails"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something but you don't know how to do it with Angular.
You use jQuery but you can do it without it :)

With your example, I see two possibles solutions :

1) You do all in your controller

You declare a directive which try to do some DOM manipulations, if you decide to not implement it like this, you can show/hide package detail with combinaison of ng-show/ng-hide and so on...
Click can be handle via ng-click.

Like this, no more DOM manipulations, no need to manually do a scope.$apply.

2) You want to do it with a directive

Your package-details directive should be an Element directive. Inside of it you can define your template as well and use bindings correctly.
You will pass your package array and loop over it.

For the click handle, two choices, pass your controller function into your directive or use your Ajaxservice in the directive. I think the second is easier than the first one and if your directive is not really generic you should consider to take this solution.

Plunker for 1 : http://goo.gl/rUzKWn

Plunker for 2 (Service): http://goo.gl/yixa7U

I'm not sure to answer your question correctly, but maybe this can give you some ideas to do what you want !